# Surprisingly different performance of simple C# program

Tags: c#, performance

Below is a simple program that with a small change, makes a significant performance impact and I don't understand why.

What the program does is not really relevant, but it calculates PI in a very convoluted way by counting collisions between two object of different mass and a wall. What I noticed as I was changing the code around was a quite large variance in performance.

The rows in question are the commented ones which are mathematically equivalent. Using the slow version makes the entire program take roughly **twice** as long as using the fast version.

```
int iterations = 0;

for (int i = 4; i < 9; i++)
{
    Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    double ms = 1.0;
    double mL = Math.Pow(100.0, i);
    double uL = 1.0;
    double us = 0.0;
    double msmLInv = 1d / (ms + mL);

    long collisions = 0;
    while (!(uL < 0 && us <= 0 && uL <= us))
    {
        Debug.Assert(++iterations > 0);
        ++collisions;

        double vs = (2 * mL * uL + us * (ms - mL)) * msmLInv;

        //double vL = (2 * ms * us - uL * (ms - mL)) * msmLInv; //fast
        double vL = uL + (us - vs) / mL; //slow


        Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(((2 * ms * us - uL * (ms - mL)) * msmLInv) - (uL + (us - vs) / mL)) < 0.001d); //checks equality between fast and slow
        if (vs > 0)
        {
            ++collisions;
            vs = -vs;
        }

        us = vs;
        uL = vL;
    }

    s.Stop();


    Debug.Assert(collisions.ToString() == "314159265359".Substring(0, i + 1)); //check the correctness
    Console.WriteLine($"i: {i}, T: {s.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000f}, PI: {collisions}");
}

Debug.Assert(iterations == 174531180); //check that we dont skip loops

Console.Write("Waiting...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

My intuition says that because the fast version has 7 operations compared to 4 operations of the slow one, the slow one should be faster, but it is not.

I disassembled the program using .NET Reflector which shows that they are mostly equal, as expected, except for the part shown below. The code before and after an identical

```
//slow
ldloc.s uL
ldloc.2 
ldloc.s us
ldloc.s vs
sub 
mul 
ldloc.3 
div 
add
```

---

```
//fast
ldc.r8 2
ldloc.2 
mul 
ldloc.s us
mul 
ldloc.s uL
ldloc.2 
ldloc.3 
sub 
mul 
sub 
ldloc.2 
ldloc.3 
add 
div
```

This also shows that more code is executing with the fast version which also would lead me to expect it to be slower.

The only guess I have right now is that the slow version causes more cache misses, but I don't know how to measure that (a guide would be welcome). Other than that I am at a loss.

---

EDIT 1.
As per the request of @EricLippert here is the disassembly from the JIT for the inner while loop where the difference is.

EDIT 2.
Solved how to break in the release program and updated the disassembly so now there seems to be some difference. I got these results by running the release version, stopping the program in the same function with a ReadKey, attaching the debugger, making the program continue execution, breaking on the next row, going into disassembly window (ctrl+alt+d)

EDIT 3.
Change the code to an updated example base on all the suggestions.

```
//slow
    78: 
    79:                     vs = (2 * mL * uL + us * (ms - mL)) / (ms + mL);
00C10530  call        CA9AD013  
00C10535  fdiv        st,st(3)  
00C10537  faddp       st(2),st  
    80: 
    81:                     //double vL = (2 * ms * us - uL * (ms - mL)) / (ms + mL); //fast
    82:                     double vL = uL + ms * (us - vs) / mL; //slow
00C10539  fldz  
00C1053B  fcomip      st,st(1)  
00C1053D  jp          00C10549  
00C1053F  jae         00C10549  
00C10541  add         ebx,1  
00C10544  adc         edi,0  
00C10547  fchs  
00C10549  fld         st(1)  
    73: 
    74:                 while (!(uL < 0 && us <= 0 && uL <= us))
00C1054B  fldz  
00C1054D  fcomip      st,st(3)  
00C1054F  fstp        st(2)  
00C10551  jp          00C10508  
00C10553  jbe         00C10508  
00C10555  fldz  
00C10557  fcomip      st,st(1)  
00C10559  jp          00C10508  
00C1055B  jb          00C10508  
00C1055D  fxch        st(1)  
00C1055F  fcomi       st,st(1)  
00C10561  jnp         00C10567  
00C10563  fxch        st(1)  
00C10565  jmp         00C10508  
00C10567  jbe         00C1056D  
00C10569  fxch        st(1)  
00C1056B  jmp         00C10508  
00C1056D  fstp        st(1)  
00C1056F  fstp        st(0)  
00C10571  fstp        st(0)  
    92:                 }
    93: 
    94:                 s.Stop();
00C10573  mov         ecx,esi  
00C10575  call        71880260  
    95: 
    96:                 Console.WriteLine($"i: {i}, T: {s.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000f}, PI: {collisions}");
00C1057A  mov         ecx,725B0994h  
00C1057F  call        00B930C8  
00C10584  mov         edx,eax  
00C10586  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
00C10589  mov         dword ptr [edx+4],eax  
00C1058C  mov         dword ptr [ebp-34h],edx  
00C1058F  mov         ecx,725F3778h  
00C10594  call        00B930C8  
00C10599  mov         dword ptr [ebp-38h],eax  
00C1059C  mov         ecx,725F2C10h  
00C105A1  call        00B930C8  
00C105A6  mov         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],eax  
00C105A9  mov         ecx,esi  
00C105AB  call        71835820  
00C105B0  push        edx  
00C105B1  push        eax  
00C105B2  push        0  
00C105B4  push        2710h  
00C105B9  call        736071A0  
00C105BE  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax  
00C105C1  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],edx  
00C105C4  fild        qword ptr [ebp-48h]  
00C105C7  fstp        dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
00C105CA  fld         dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
00C105CD  fdiv        dword ptr ds:[0C10678h]  
00C105D3  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-38h]  
00C105D6  fstp        dword ptr [eax+4]  
00C105D9  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-38h]  
00C105DC  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-3Ch]  
00C105DF  mov         dword ptr [eax+4],ebx  
00C105E2  mov         dword ptr [eax+8],edi  
00C105E5  mov         esi,dword ptr [ebp-3Ch]  
00C105E8  lea         edi,[ebp-30h]  
00C105EB  xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
00C105EE  movq        mmword ptr [edi],xmm0  
00C105F2  movq        mmword ptr [edi+8],xmm0  
00C105F7  push        edx  
00C105F8  push        esi  
00C105F9  lea         ecx,[ebp-30h]  
00C105FC  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-34h]  
00C105FF  call        724A2ED4  
00C10604  lea         eax,[ebp-30h]  
00C10607  push        dword ptr [eax+0Ch]  
00C1060A  push        dword ptr [eax+8]  
00C1060D  push        dword ptr [eax+4]  
00C10610  push        dword ptr [eax]  
00C10612  mov         edx,dword ptr ds:[3832310h]  
00C10618  xor         ecx,ecx  
00C1061A  call        72497A00  
00C1061F  mov         ecx,eax  
00C10621  call        72571934  
    61:             for (int i = 4; i < 9; i++)
00C10626  inc         dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
00C10629  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-14h],9  
00C1062D  jl          00C10496  
    97:             }
    98: 
    99:             Console.WriteLine(loops);
00C10633  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-10h]  
00C10636  call        72C583FC  
   100:             Console.Write("Waiting...");
00C1063B  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[3832314h]  
00C10641  call        724C67F0  
00C10646  lea         ecx,[ebp-20h]  
00C10649  xor         edx,edx  
00C1064B  call        72C57984  
00C10650  lea         esp,[ebp-0Ch]  
00C10653  pop         ebx  
00C10654  pop         esi  
00C10655  pop         edi  
00C10656  pop         ebp  
00C10657  ret
```

---

```
//fast
 80: 
    81:                     double vL = (2 * ms * us - uL * (ms - mL)) / (ms + mL); //fast
02FD0550  or          al,83h  
    80: 
    81:                     double vL = (2 * ms * us - uL * (ms - mL)) / (ms + mL); //fast
02FD0552  ret  
02FD0553  add         dword ptr [ebx-3626FF29h],eax  
02FD0559  fchs  
02FD055B  fxch        st(1)  
02FD055D  fld         st(0)  
    73: 
    74:                 while (!(uL < 0 && us <= 0 && uL <= us))
02FD055F  fldz  
02FD0561  fcomip      st,st(2)  
02FD0563  fstp        st(1)  
02FD0565  jnp         02FD056B  
02FD0567  fxch        st(1)  
02FD0569  jmp         02FD050B  
02FD056B  ja          02FD0571  
02FD056D  fxch        st(1)  
02FD056F  jmp         02FD050B  
02FD0571  fldz  
02FD0573  fcomip      st,st(2)  
02FD0575  jnp         02FD057B  
02FD0577  fxch        st(1)  
02FD0579  jmp         02FD050B  
02FD057B  jae         02FD0581  
02FD057D  fxch        st(1)  
02FD057F  jmp         02FD050B  
02FD0581  fcomi       st,st(1)  
02FD0583  jnp         02FD0589  
02FD0585  fxch        st(1)  
02FD0587  jmp         02FD050B  
02FD0589  jbe         02FD0592  
02FD058B  fxch        st(1)  
02FD058D  jmp         02FD050B  
02FD0592  fstp        st(1)  
02FD0594  fstp        st(0)  
    92:                 }
    93: 
    94:                 s.Stop();
02FD0596  mov         ecx,esi  
02FD0598  call        71880260  
    95: 
    96:                 Console.WriteLine($"i: {i}, T: {s.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000f}, PI: {collisions}");
02FD059D  mov         ecx,725B0994h  
02FD05A2  call        013830C8  
02FD05A7  mov         edx,eax  
02FD05A9  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
02FD05AC  mov         dword ptr [edx+4],eax  
02FD05AF  mov         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],edx  
02FD05B2  mov         ecx,725F3778h  
02FD05B7  call        013830C8  
02FD05BC  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax  
02FD05BF  mov         ecx,725F2C10h  
02FD05C4  call        013830C8  
02FD05C9  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax  
02FD05CC  mov         ecx,esi  
02FD05CE  call        71835820  
02FD05D3  push        edx  
02FD05D4  push        eax  
02FD05D5  push        0  
02FD05D7  push        2710h  
02FD05DC  call        736071A0  
02FD05E1  mov         dword ptr [ebp-50h],eax  
02FD05E4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],edx  
02FD05E7  fild        qword ptr [ebp-50h]  
02FD05EA  fstp        dword ptr [ebp-48h]  
02FD05ED  fld         dword ptr [ebp-48h]  
02FD05F0  fdiv        dword ptr ds:[2FD06A8h]  
02FD05F6  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
02FD05F9  fstp        dword ptr [eax+4]  
02FD05FC  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
02FD05FF  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-44h]  
02FD0602  mov         dword ptr [eax+4],ebx  
02FD0605  mov         dword ptr [eax+8],edi  
02FD0608  mov         esi,dword ptr [ebp-44h]  
02FD060B  lea         edi,[ebp-38h]  
02FD060E  xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
02FD0611  movq        mmword ptr [edi],xmm0  
02FD0615  movq        mmword ptr [edi+8],xmm0  
02FD061A  push        edx  
02FD061B  push        esi  
02FD061C  lea         ecx,[ebp-38h]  
02FD061F  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-3Ch]  
02FD0622  call        724A2ED4  
02FD0627  lea         eax,[ebp-38h]  
02FD062A  push        dword ptr [eax+0Ch]  
02FD062D  push        dword ptr [eax+8]  
02FD0630  push        dword ptr [eax+4]  
02FD0633  push        dword ptr [eax]  
02FD0635  mov         edx,dword ptr ds:[4142310h]  
02FD063B  xor         ecx,ecx  
02FD063D  call        72497A00  
02FD0642  mov         ecx,eax  
02FD0644  call        72571934  
    61:             for (int i = 4; i < 9; i++)
02FD0649  inc         dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
02FD064C  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-14h],9  
02FD0650  jl          02FD0496  
    97:             }
    98: 
    99:             Console.WriteLine(loops);
02FD0656  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-10h]  
02FD0659  call        72C583FC  
   100:             Console.Write("Waiting...");
02FD065E  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[4142314h]  
02FD0664  call        724C67F0  
02FD0669  lea         ecx,[ebp-28h]  
02FD066C  xor         edx,edx  
02FD066E  call        72C57984  
02FD0673  lea         esp,[ebp-0Ch]  
02FD0676  pop         ebx  
02FD0677  pop         esi  
02FD0678  pop         edi  
02FD0679  pop         ebp  
02FD067A  ret
```

---

Comment: I didn't check this in detail, but it all looks somewhat complicated, also the condition in the loop header. Are you entirely sure that there isn't a minor logical error causing the inner loop to run a different amount of times? You could insert a dumb counter variable in the inner loop an count the number of runs before/after just to be safe.

Comment: `calculates PI in a very convoluted way by counting collisions between two object of different mass and a wall` - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEfHFsfGXjs?

Comment: @DanDan Both versions run 174531180 loops. The reason why the exit condition looks complicated is i figured out when it should exit first and didnt bother restating it so i just changed it with a NOT.

Comment: @GSerg indeed, but i got distracted :)

Comment: This is a very odd result! I cannot see any way that it can be cache misses. A better guess would be register scheduling in the FP registers. Are you doing your measurements in a release build and not in the debugger? Measuring performance in the debugger can cause register scheduling to be deoptimized.

Comment: @EricLippert Im running in release without the debugger attached. And the run times are very stable, they only differ about 0.1%

Comment: My best guess is register scheduling by the jitter then; it would be interesting to look at the generated code for both versions and see how they differ.

Comment: @EricLippert Is there anyway i can messure if it is register scheduling? I have been trying to learn perfview but im not very good at it yet. How can i get a hold of the generated code?

Comment: It is a little tricky to get the generated code. Usually what I do in these situations is start the program outside of the debugger, but put a "readline" or some such thing that makes it pause just as it is about to finish; it has to be *after* all the code has jitted. Then while the program is paused, attach a debugger and force execution to step back into the method, and then look at the disassembly in the debugger. That way you definitely see the method as it was jitted without the debugger attached.

Comment: @EricLippert Added dissasembly from the release build

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the reason is CPU [instruction pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining). your slow equation depends on `vs`, that means `vs` must be calculated first, then `vl` is calculated.

but in your fast equation, more instructions can be pipelined as `vs` and `vl` can be calculated at same time because they don't depend on each other.

Please don't confuse this with multi threading. Instruction pipelining is some thing implemented at very low hardware level and tries to exploit as many CPU modules as possible at the same time to achieve maximum instruction throughput.

Comment: Interesting idea, i hadnt thought about pipelining and i agree that there will be more divisions in the slow version which are expesive but it seems unlikely to make that large difference. I did a few simple test by double o = 1d/us and o=1d/vs seperatly and then used them in the if statement to prevent to from being removed by optimization. This did not make any significant difference on the runtime though. Do you have any other ideas how to test that?

Comment: instruction pipelining is something implemented at hardware level. so in order to test that you should run this code on a processor without pipelining feature and compare slow and fast versions on that computer.

Comment: @Imapler for division i did not notice one thing important. your fast code has literally no division inside the loop.

Comment: @Imapler ok, division is not the reason. both equation divisions are optimized away outside of the loop. i guess only thing that remains is instruction pipelining.

Comment: Good catch however the compiler does not move it outside the loop. I precalculated the 1d/(ms+mL)and how it takes 2/3 of the time.

Comment: @Imapler if you run that code on release mode with optimizations turned on, you probably get same results. go to `Project => Myproject Properties... => Build => Configuration=Release => tick Optimize code`. It should be enabled by default. Just switch to release mode from the toolbar.

Comment: i thought so too but optimization has been turned on the whole time.

Comment: @Imapler I get same results whether i put division inside or outside of the loop. the compiler that you are using and its version also matters. get the latest updates for better results. my compiler version is 4.7.3190.0

Comment: I think pipelining is the answer. As a simpler test, I stripped the calculation down to just the inner while-loop running over a fixed number of iterations (ex: 314159265) and performed just the calculations of `vs` and `vl` keeping `ms, ml, ul, and us` constant. I find the slow calculation is still slow and the fast still fast. However, if I promote `vs` to a constant outside of the loop and just calculate `vl` in the loop, both have about the same speed (actually "slow" is slightly faster.)

Comment: It seems resonable so i accepted the answer but is there any way to design for pipelineing, i dont understand why one is pipelined and the other is not?

Comment: Processor will always do the pipelining when ever possible. There is a dedicated piece of hardware for each stage of performing instructions per core. Such as fetch, decode, execute, write etc... when instruction B does not depend on instruction A, processor can fetch instruction B while decoding  instruction A. It can then decode instruction B while executing  instruction A as well as fetching instruction C all at the same time. Because those pieces of hardware for each stage are seperate from each other. In your slow formula, you are using variable `vs`.

Comment: Only after `vs` is calculated, processor can proceed to calculate `ms*(us - vs)/mL`. This part can not be pipelined. Because it doesnt know the value of `vs` until its fully calculated. @Impaler

Comment: Note that in my explanation, i missed a lot of details about instruction pipelining. It could be misleading as well. It is a complex structure and i dont know it well. But I think there are some good articles about that on the internet.

Answer (score 5):

You calculations are not equal

```
double vL = (2 * ms * us - uL * (ms - mL)) / (ms + mL); //fast
double vL = uL + ms * (us - vs) / mL; //slow
```

Example: I miss `vs` in the fast version

I expect your while loop doing more iterations because of this?

Comment: Good thought, i ran the experiment and both variants run 174531180 iterations so no difference there. The equations looks quite different but they are derived using the conservation of momentum and energy. The difference is that the slow one uses the result from the first calculations while the fast recalculates everything.

Comment: And if you do both computations and compare the two values, they are always within a very small fraction of each other. They appear to be equivalent computations.

Comment: @EricLippert Math.Abs(vL1 - vL2) > 0.001f is never true

Comment: They are mathematically equal, you can prove that just by algebra operations.

Comment: I double checked with equation solver fast and slow are not equal: vL = uL + (2 * ms * (us - uL)) / (ms + mL); //slow
            vL = (2 * ms * us - uL * (ms - mL)) / (ms + mL); //fast